# visual studio 2022 entity db first model drag drop problem

Tags: drag-and-drop, visual-studio-2022

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjcwz.png)
When i try to drag drop tables from emdx model it crashes visual studio 2022.
I am trying same project on visual studio 2019 there is no problem.